# serverless website upload/download to S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the current best practice if I want to allow a user to have a local html/js website that can upload and download files from an Amazon S3 bucket, as an anonymous user?

I.E. I would like to load a local version of index.html in my browser, and access a previously set up (public?) s3 bucket, and not require the user to be logged in to Amazon, or any other identity service. (I am aware of the pitfalls of using a public s3 bucket)

Is my only option to use the AWS javascript SDK, and an Unauthenticated user as mentioned here?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/authentication-with-amazon-cognito-in-the-browser/

Answer (score 0):

That is the only reasonably safe, reasonably viable solution... assuming it will work with a local file.

It's technically possible to write to a bucket using ordinary HTTP `PUT` requests by setting bucket policy accordingly, but... *here be dragons.*  If your bucket allows anonymous access, then it's relatively trivial for anyone to upload objects to your bucket that you cannot access, at all, other than to delete them.

Usually, when someone asks about anonymous access, they're trying to save some effort... but the effort saved is not likely to be worth the potential cost.